# Как вычисляется длина хеш-таблицы?

Tags: java, коллекции, java-hashmap

Уважаемые коллеги, столкнулся с таким вопросом касаемо хэш-таблицы, подскажите пожалуйста:

Понятно что каждая ячейка массива может быть либо связанным списком, либо деревом. А как определяется длинна самого массива? Есть ли какой-то обобщенный принцип что-бы мы могли сказать что-то вроде: *"контекст в котором данная таблица будет использована, такой-то такой-то, и поэтому мы считаем длину ее массива по такой-то формуле."*

Или какие-нибудь, твердо обосновывающие решение о длине критерии, которыми необходимо руководствоваться, при создании своей таблицы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> А как определяется длинна самого массива?

По-умолчанию, создается массив на 16 элементов (корзин).

У `HashMap` есть такие атрибуты, как:

- `capacity` – вместимость/емкость (текущий размер массива, *полем класса не является*);
- `size` – количество элементов, находящихся в `HashMap`;
- `loadFactor` – коэффициент загрузки;
- `threshold` – пороговое значение количества элементов `HashMap`'а.

При этом `threshold` рассчитывается как `capacity * load factor`.

После добавления пары в `HashMap` происходит проверка:

```
if (size++ >= threshold)
```

и, если количество элементов `HashMap`'а равно или превышает пороговое значение, то создается новый массив, размер которого в два раза больше размера старого массива:

```
resize(2 * table.length);
```

при этом все элементы старого массива распределяются в новый массив и изменяется значение `capacity` и пересчитывается `threshold`.

**Пример:**

Создали `HashMap` с параметрами по-умолчанию:

- `capacity = 16`
- `size = 0`
- `loadFactor = 0.75`
- `threshold = (int)(16 * 0.75f) = 12`

Добавили 11 различных пар:

- `capacity = 16`
- `size = 11`
- `loadFactor = 0.75`
- `threshold = 12`

После добавления 12-й пары получаем:

- `capacity = 32`
- `size = 12`
- `loadFactor = 0.75`
- `threshold = (int)(32 * 0.75f) = 24`

*Все вышенаписанное справедливо для JDK 7 и ниже, а вот в JDK 8 расширение таблицы происходит несколько иначе.*

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ. А не могли бы вы еще немного пояснить 1. В чем идея 'loadFactor' – коэффициент загрузки это константа '0.75' для вычисления 'threshold'? Или он где то еще фигурирует? 2. 'capacity' и 'table.length' это одно и то-же?

Comment: 1. `loadFactor` – это коэффициент, который определяет момент перестроения хэш-таблицы (используется только для вычисления `threshold`). Значение 0.75 способствует лучшей производительности с точки зрения памяти и времени. Несколько вольное объяснение, но суть, думаю, донес. 2. Да, они оба имеют одно и то же значение.

Answer (score 1):

Если мы создаем `Map hashMap = new Hashmap()`

То по умолчанию размер `busket`-a 16 и коэффициент нагрузки 0,75(load factor).
Когда число записей в хэш-таблице превышает коэффициента нагрузки, то она в два раза увеличивает размет `busket`-a.

Так же можно задать размер `busket`-a

```
HashMap(int initialCapacity)

HashMap(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor)
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: Исчерпывающе о том *как*, но ни слова по сути вопроса (хотя ТС ответ и принял), т.е. о том, *чем именно надо руководствоваться* (или хотя бы о чем думать самому) выбирая конкретные значения `initialCapacity` и `loadFactor`

Comment: `То по умолчанию размер busket-a 16` – а что такое размер `busket`-a? Может все-таки размер массива? `Когда число записей в хэш-таблице превышает коэффициента нагрузки` – число записей в хэш-таблице будет превышать значение коэффициента нагрузки уже после добавления одного элемента (при параметрах по-умолчанию).